# Could not uninstall Net framework 4.5.1

Tags: uninstall, .net-framework

When I tried to uninstall framework 4.5.1, I got this problem as shown by this picture

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xSL9ZNv.png]

I had tried Net CleanUp, but the problem still remains. In my computer, I already installed framework 4 and the latest version 4.5.1. My computer had experienced system restore and cause this problem occurs. From now, I cannot open framework 4 applications even I already installed on my computer. What I want is uninstall all the frameworks but I could not do for framework 4.5.1 but 4.

Comment: expand the Offline installer (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779) with 7-zip and point to this folder. Does this help?